# Failing to load Emscripten-compiled C++ in Vue

Tags: webpack, webassembly, emscripten

Just to be clear, I'm not a C++ expert

I have this C++ code:

```cpp
#include <emscripten.h>
#include <string>

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
std::string test(std::string parameter) {
    return parameter;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it using:

```
cmake.exe --build cmake-build-emscripten --target data_converter -s EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=[cwrap] -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=[_test] -s EXPORT_ES6=1 -s MODULARIZE=1 -s USE_ES6_IMPORT_META=1
```

Note that my IDE is CLion, in which my CMake configurations are:
Environment:

```
CC=C:\repositories\c++\data-converter\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\emcc.bat;CXX=C:\repositories\c++\data-converter\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\em++.bat;AR=C:\repositories\c++\data-converter\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\emar.bat;LD=C:\repositories\c++\data-converter\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\emcc.bat;NM=C:\repositories\c++\data-converter\emsdk\upstream\bin\llvm-nm.exe;LDSHARED=C:\repositories\c++\data-converter\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\emcc.bat;RANLIN=C:\repositories\c++\data-converter\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\emranlib.bat;EMMAKEN_COMPILER=C:\repositories\c++\data-converter\emsdk\upstream\bin\clang++.exe;EMSCRIPTEN_TOOLS=C:\repositories\c++\data-converter\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\tools;HOST_CC=C:\repositories\c++\data-converter\emsdk\upstream\bin\clang.exe;HOST_CXX=C:\repositories\c++\data-converter\emsdk\upstream\bin\clang++.exe;HOST_CFLAGS=-W;HOST_CXXFLAGS=-W;EMSCRIPTEN=C:\repositories\c++\data-converter\emsdk\upstream\emscripten
```

Build options:

```
-s EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=["cwrap"] -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=["_test"] -s EXPORT_ES6=1 -s MODULARIZE=1 -s USE_ES6_IMPORT_META=1
```

Project structure:

```
<Vue root>
  └ src
     └ data
         └ wasm
             └ data_converter.js
             └ data_converter.wasm
```

Then, I moved the `data_converter.js` and `data_converter.wasm` to `<Vue root>\src\data\wasm`

My Vue code has:

```
<script>
import Module from "./data/wasm/data_converter";

export default {
  created() {
    const test = Module().cwrap("test", "string", ["string"]);
    console.log(test("Hello world"));
  }
};
</script>
```

When I try to load the component:

```
Uncaught (in promise) RuntimeError: abort(CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 3c 21 44 4f @+0). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.
    at abort (webpack-internal:///./src/data/wasm/data_converter.js:875:9)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/data/wasm/data_converter.js:959:7)

[Vue warn]: Error in created hook (Promise/async): "TypeError: _data_wasm_data_converter__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_48___default(...) is not a function"

found in

---> <App> at src/App.vue
       <Root>
```

---

### Failed attempt #2

Since I'm using Webpack, I installed [wasm-loader](https://npmjs.com/package/wasm-loader), my `vue.config.js` roughly looks like:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.wasm$/,
          loaders: ["wasm-loader"]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in the component:

```js
import Module from "./data/wasm/data_converter";

export default {
  // ...
  async created() {
    const instance = await Module();
    const test = instance.exports._test;
    console.log(test("Hello world"));
  }
};
```

The error is the same as the aforementioned one.

Comment: I think both of these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343425/not-able-to-bind-function-in-emscripten) would be helpful. The only thing that might be wrong in the second answer is according to the [docs](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html), is the option for exposing free functions seems to be `EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS`.

Answer (score 0):

`3c 21 44 4f` is `<!DO`, or the start of a HTML document. Are you sure the import is resolved at compile time or that the fetch at runtime works?

Check with the network inspector to see the result of fetching the WASM module.

Comment: In the actual code, the filename is `data_converter.wasm`. [Here is a screenshot.](https://i.imgur.com/olfH74v.png) Now I see that the request URL is `/js/data_converter.wasm` - that's because the `vue-cli-service` is using Webpack to bundle the code, which results in creating a `js/` directory, to which the `.wasm` is being moved.

Comment: I'm using [wasm-loader](https://npmjs.com/package/wasm-loader). Now, whenever I try to import `data_converter` (which results in `data_converter.js`), I'm getting the error in the first post. Otherwise, if I'm attempting to import `data_converter.wasm`, [this is the error](https://i.imgur.com/HEobNsU.png).

Comment: Your first comment hides the most important part: the response headers! I'm guessing the Content-Type there is `text/html` instead of WASM. Probably some error page. What do you get if you fetch that url directly?

Comment: As for your second attempt: what are the first few bytes of your `.wasm` file? Should be `00 61 73 6d`.

Comment: Indeed, they are